# absoluteTime vs wallClockTime - Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-notifications, timing, flutter-ios, flutter-notification

I know the definitions:

> **absoluteTime:** The date is interpreted as absolute GMT time.
>
> **wallClockTime:** The date is interpreted as a wall-clock time.

But can't figure out **when to use which one**. For example, which one should I use for a *reminder app*?

[Flutters core documents, Where I found the definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b07f6.jpg)

```
\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_local_notifications-8.2.0\lib\src\platform_specifics\ios\enums.dart
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where did you see these definitions?  Normally [wall clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elapsed_real_time) is used in contrast to things such as [CPU time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time) and is used to measure *duration*.

Comment: @jamesdlin I saw them in flutter's core documents. In "\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_local_notifications-8.2.0\lib\src\platform_specifics\ios\enums.dart" to be exact.

Comment: That's a file from a third-party package.  I suspect that the intended distinction is about whether to account Daylight Saving Time for timezones that observe DST.  Which you choose depends on the situation, but most users probably would expect to set reminders in their local wall-clock time.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks for your information. Though, I'm not quite sure yet.